# Least Squares with Total Variation Regularization - How to Set the Lambda ($ \lambda $) Parameter?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regularization, total-variation

I am trying to use total-variation minimization for an image reconstruction problem. Essentially, I am trying to penalize different in the intensity of the two pixels in the reconstructed image. For this, I minimize $|Ax-b|+ \lambda |F(X)|$, where $F(x)= (x_i - x_i+1)^2$ is a quadratic function that penalizes the difference intensity of two nearest pixels. I am, however, unable to decide how to fix the value of $\lambda$ (strength of regularization). In literature, I found ways to find $\lambda$ for the case of norm regularization using Lagrange multipliers. However, I am unable to find/formulate a method to find optimal $\lambda$  for this case. Anyone  has any idea about how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you write the problem as:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \left\| D x \right\|_{1} $$

You can treat it as a [Maximum A Posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) (MAP) Problem.
In this case the assumption is that the derivative of the data is distributed according to [Laplace Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) with zero mean and its variance depends on $ \lambda $.
Now you can set $ \lambda $ according to your knowledge about the distribution of the data.
You can even try fit it and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually lambda would be determined by some kind of cross-validation or bootstrapping, i.e. fit random subsets of the data.

Comment: I was searching if one can derive an analytical expression for finding \lambda? it is becoming computationally very expensive to use a bootstrapping method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the heuristic discrepancy rule (sometimes also called the Hanke-Raus rule),

$$\lambda_\ast=\operatorname{argmin}_\lambda\frac{\|Ax_\lambda-b\|}{\sqrt{\lambda}},$$

which is perhaps the "analytical" way to determine the parameter that you were asking for.